# Kafka JDBC connector not picking up new commits

Tags: apache-kafka

I am currently using a Kafka JDBC connector to poll records from an Oracle db. The connector properties are set to use timestamp mode and we have provided a simple select query in the properties (not using a where clause) - based on my understanding this should work.

However currently when instantiating the connector I can see the initial query does pull out all of the records it should and does publish them to the Kafka consumer - but any new commits to the oracle db are not picked up and the connector just sits polling without finding any new info, and maintaining its offset.

No exceptions are being thrown in the connector, and no indication of a problem other than it is not picking up the new commits in the db.

One thing of note, which i have been unable to prove makes a difference, is that the fields in the oracle db are all nullable. But i have tested changing that for the timestamp field, and it had no effect and the same behaviour continued. I have also tested in bulk mode and it works fine and does pick up new commits, though I cannot use bulk mode as we cannot duplicate the records for the system.

Does anyone have any idea why the connector is unable to pick up new commits for timestamp mode?

Answer (score 0):

What does your properties file look like? You need to make sure to use an incrementing column or a time stamp column.
If you you are using a time stamp column, is it getting updated on the commit? 
Regarding nulls, You can tweak your query to coalesce the null column to a value.  Alternatively, I think there is a setting to allow nullable columns.